# Nuance between « Est-ce que ça serait pas » and « Est-ce que ça serait »

Tags: sens

> {in the negative} : C'est quoi, ça ? Est-ce que ça **serait pas** le doux parfum d’une donzelle ?

I wonder how using the negative construction differs in meaning from saying in the affirmative:

> {in the affirmative} : C'est quoi, ça ? Est-ce que ça **serait** le doux parfum d’une donzelle ?

Does the negative construction convey a higher degree of uncertainty than the affirmative version? If so, would you attach the phrase « par hasard » to the end of the negative one, but not to the affirmative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is using a lazy, colloquial French grammar and *le doux parfum d'une donzelle* is partly literary, partly humorous.

> — C'est quoi, ça ? Est-ce que ça serait pas le doux parfum d’une donzelle ?

literary version:

> — Qu'est-ce ? Ne serait-ce pas le doux parfum d’une donzelle ?

The second one, while possible, is less idiomatic.

> — C'est quoi, ça ? Est-ce que ça serait le doux parfum d’une donzelle ?

literary:

> — Qu'est-ce ? Serait-ce le doux parfum d’une donzelle ?

The reason why the first form is preferred is because it is using an *interronégative au conditionnel* which suggests more a positive answer. The second form is more neutral. See for example this document [*La négation et l'orientation de la demande de confirmation*](http://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_1979_num_44_1_6169), *Andrée Borillo*.

Despite being seemingly opposite questions, both can be given the same answers :

> — *Oui* (or *si* for the negative question), *c'est le parfum d'une donzelle.*
>
> — *Non, ce n'est pas le parfum d'une donzelle.*

Comment: The first version using the “interronégative au conditionnel” (that’s a cool term, imo!) sounds like how a justifiably suspicious spouse would frame the question (and I can easily imagine a “par hasard” being thrown in for good measure!). In fact, just hearing the question in the conditional as in version 2 would still make me think the jig is up, but I’d still much rather hear it than version 1!

Answer (score 1):

> C'est quoi, ça ? Est-ce que ça serait pas le doux parfum d’une
>   donzelle ?

C'est un langage très parlé, sûrement un dialogue de roman, prononcé par un personnage populaire. On trouve le mot "donzelle" qui est clairement argotique.c On voit qu'il manque la négation, ici: pour imiter le langage parlé.

Avec la négation: Est-ce que ça **ne** serait pas...

Mais, même si le "ne" n'apparaît pas (pour imiter le langage parlé), il s'agit bien d'une négation.

Il n'y pas de différence de degré entre le fait de mettre le "ne" ou de ne pas le mettre. La forme correcte doit avoir le "ne", mais dans les romans, on l'enlève souvent, car à l'oral, on le "saute" facilement, surtout quand on parle d'une façon détendue.

Même chose à l'écrit, quand on envoie un message à quelqu'un on "saute" souvent le "ne" (surtout quand on tutoie par exemple), et ça ne choque personne de prendre une petite liberté avec la grammaire. Par contre, si je devais écrire une lettre ou quelque chose d'officiel, la faute sauterait aux yeux, ce ne serait pas forcément bien pris.

Comment: You cover well the reasons that can explain the omission of “ne” in negations  and also [the lack of] any difference in meaning when the “ne” isn’t there, but I think the OP is also looking for any nuance in meaning between the negated version (with or without the “ne”) and the non-negated one.  (Sorry for the intrusion, especially if my interpretation of the question is wrong!)

Comment: You're welcome to ask any question or request for answer improvement. There's no differences between the properly negated and the not properly negated (both are negated, even without the "ne", as the negation is really in the "pas".). The one that is not properly is only a lot more colloquial and "parlé". "Il n'y pas de différence de degré entre le fait de mettre le "ne" ou de ne pas le mettre."

Comment: I'm afraid you are still insisting about a point that is not the one discussed by the OP and then seem to be missing that the second question "*Est-ce que ça serait le doux parfum d’une donzelle ?*" is fully affirmative, i.e. not negated at all.